# XNA Rotation results in a pixelated image

Tags: xna, c#

I have a "problem" with XNA 4 and spriteBatch. When I draw a rectangle and rotate it, the sides get quite pixelated and look bad: example:

[image]

What do I need to do to make the edges look smooth?

```
spriteBatch.Draw(box, new Rectangle(350, 350, 100, 100), null, Color.Red,MathHelper.ToRadians(65), new Vector2(50, 50), SpriteEffects.None, 0.0F);
```

EDIT: Found the solution.

As Tetrad's comment suggested, one needs to activate anti-aliasing. Under XNA4.0 you can use this code

```
GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
graphics.PreferMultiSampling = true;
graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

Comment: What you're seeing is "aliasing".  You need to turn on anti-aliasing, but I don't know how to do that with XNA.

Comment: Does ApplyChanges() do anything special? I set the graphics settings on game initialization with and without it and don't notice a difference.

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer - it's ok, you're allowed to do that! :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to activate [anti-aliasing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.renderstate.multisampleantialias%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx) on your rendering device:

```
/* Your graphics device manager */
GraphicsDeviceManager gdm;
/* ... */
gdm.Device.RenderState.MultiSampleAntiAlias = true;
/* optional: */
gdm.Device.PresentationParameters.MultiSampleType =  MultiSampleType.SixteenSamples;
gdm.Device.PresentationParameters.MultiSampleQuality = 8;
```

Comment: There is no RenderState/Device under the GraphicsDeviceManager in XNA4.0!

Comment: Try "gdm.PreferMultisampling = true;" and possibly gdm.GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.MultiSampleCount = 8;

Answer (score 1):

did you pass SpriteBlendMode.AlphaBlend into the spritebatch.begin?

`spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.AlphaBlend);`